# How to sort files according to the creation date on my computer on Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

For a downloaded file, the current "Date modified" or "Date created" seems to be the date of modification/creation on the original computer.

I don't care about that. And this has caused a mess in my folder of downloads.

So how do I sort these files according to my computer's creation/modification date?

Comment: If you delete-and-recreate a file on windows, it may interpret that as a 'modification' instead of a 'creation'. Is that what you are doing with your downloads?

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows Explorer and the folder you wish to sort.

Set to details.

Right click on an area of the Detail title bar, select More, and then a sub-window opens.

Date Created is in this list (default is OFF). Turn it ON and you can then sort by details.

You may be able to set this for All Folders in Options.